# Como traer varios valores de una columna separados por comas en oracle 18-c?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-18c

espero y me puedan ayudar por favor, tengo una consulta donde me trae un registro un solo registro, esta es mi sentencia:

```
SELECT 
cta_que_factura, tipo_documento, 
id_estatus, uuid, FECHA_CREACION, 
NOM_SISTEMA, serie
from 
complemento_pago 
WHERE 
TIPO_DOCUMENTO =4 AND ID_ESTATUS =6 AND UUID IS NULL 
and TO_DATE(FECHA_CREACION, 'DD/MM/RRRR') = TO_DATE(sysdate, 'DD/MM/RRRR') - (select valor from parametros where ID_PARAMETRO =334)
and nom_sistema = Upper((select valor from parametros where id_parametro =335))
And serie = (
    SELECT (
        CASE valor 
        WHEN '1'  THEN 'PA'
        WHEN '2' THEN 'PB'
        WHEN '3' THEN 'PC'
        WHEN '4' THEN 'PD'
        WHEN '5' THEN 'PE'
        WHEN '6' THEN 'PF'
        WHEN '7' THEN 'PG'
        WHEN '8' THEN 'PH'
        WHEN '9' THEN 'PI'
        END
    ) 
    FROM parametros 
    where id_parametro = 336
);
```

y de resultado me trae lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema sería:
Como puedo traerme los valores de mi tabla parametros del registro Valor y que me traiga lo que encuentre de la columna `Valor`, es decir que ya no sea un solo valor sino los que están en dicha columna? es decir si vienen `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...`, que me traiga los registros que coincidan.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podrían por favor ayudarme con este problema, se los agradecería mucho, quedo al pendiente de sus comentarios y si hay alguna duda con gusto la aclararé, saludos

Comment: Pues ahora la pregunta no se entiende

Comment: Hola buenos dias, el problema es que solo me trae un registro ya que en el campo tiene 1, la idea es que me regrese mas registros por ejm en campo valor tenga 1,2 pues que esos me le regrese, no se si me di a entender amigo? XD

Comment: Espero que la respuesta sirva. De paso, procura indentar las consultas de forma que se puedan leer fácil y seguir la lógica. Yo uso la indentación que ves ahora en la pregunta pero puedes elegir otras opciones. Lo importante es que puedas validar fácilmente la sintaxis correcta y el uso de los datos

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas es hacer un join de algún tipo entre una tabla con todos los valores en tu parámetro, y el resultSet que estás armando.

Para tener tu lista de valores con comas como una tabla, puedes usar `regexp_substr` de esta forma (ahí hasta usamos una cosa que se llama *hierarchical queries*):

```
select 
regexp_substr((select valor from parametros where id_parametro = 336),'[^,]+', 1, level) VALORES_PARAM
from dual
connect by 
regexp_substr((select valor from parametros where id_parametro = 336), '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

Esta consulta recorre la cadena de valores separados por comas, busca cada coma y separa la cadena usando la coma como delimitador. Retorna cada cadena resultante cada vez que encuentra una coma. Te va a devolver algo como:

```
VALORES_PARAM
------------------------
1
2
3
4
5
...
```

Lo siguiente será entonces hacer un CTE para facilitar el uso de ese resultado. Lo que va dentro del `WITH parametro_cte AS(...)` será esta consulta y podrás usarla como una tabla más que se llama `parametro_cte`. No pongo la consulta completa porque pereza pero se entiende -espero-.

```
WITH parametro_cte AS (select regexp_substr...)
SELECT 
cta_que_factura, tipo_documento, 
...
And serie = (
    SELECT (
        CASE VALORES_PARAM
        WHEN '1'  THEN 'PA'
        WHEN '2' THEN 'PB'
        ...
        END
    ) 
    FROM parametro_cte
);
```

*Parcialmente siguiendo [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44260309/236345).*

Comment: Hola buenas tardes amigos, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero hice mal mi analisis, volveré a actualizar la pregunta, saludos

Comment: @cratus666jose respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Hola buenas tardes amigos, opté por hacerlo en java ya que no encontré mas opciones, dejaré mi respuesta a como quedaría, pero es código duro, lo que estoy haciendo en java es traer esa condición, te anexo el link de otra pregunta que hice:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/386841/problemas-con-mi-metodo#386841 
Primeramente antes que todo,lo estoy haciendo en consulta ya que posteriormente será un update, al igual vi que pusiste en tu respuesta la clausula with,y tengo entendido que solo funciona para los select, de verdad te agradezco por tu respuesta amigo, saludos y que estes bien

Comment: Nunca supe si te sirvió lo que te sugerí hacer pero bueh, buena suerte con tu código. Y no, defintivamente tienes que leer sobre CTE porque estás partiendo de supuestos

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cta_que_factura, tipo_documento,id_estatus, uuid, FECHA_CREACION, NOM_SISTEMA, serie
    from complemento_pago WHERE TIPO_DOCUMENTO =4 AND ID_ESTATUS =6 AND UUID IS NULL 
        and TO_DATE(FECHA_CREACION, 'DD/MM/RRRR') =  TO_DATE(sysdate, 'DD/MM/RRRR')-(select valor from parametros where ID_PARAMETRO =334)
        and nom_sistema = Upper((select valor from parametros where id_parametro =335))                                    
        And serie in ('PE', 'PA')
```