# Problemas con mi metodo

Tags: java, array, string, split

Hola Amigos buenas tardes, espero y me puedan ayudar por favor, lo que pasa es que estoy desarrollando un metodo donde se encarga de extraer los valores de una consulta que java manda a ejecutar, anexo el código:

```
public String cadenasRegionesAprocesarUpdate() throws CPagoException {
        String capturaRegiones ="";
        String cadenaRegiones ="";
        String capturaSerie = "";
        String separador =",";
        String cadenaSerieCompleta="";
        try{
            LOGGER.info("Consulta region a procesar de tabla Parametros JJ <<<<<-----");
            List<ParametrosVO> listRegion = jdbcTPARAM.query(getQueryMapper().getQueryConsultaRegionProcesar().toString(),new ParametrosMapper<ParametrosVO>());            
            for (ParametrosVO parametrosVO : listRegion) {
                capturaRegiones=parametrosVO.getValor();
            }
                        
            cadenaRegiones = capturaRegiones;
            String[] arrayRegiones = cadenaRegiones.split(",");
            
                        
            for (String numeroRegion : arrayRegiones) {             
                capturaSerie =capturaNumeroRegion(cadenaRegiones);
            }
            
            
//          for (int i=0; i<=arrayRegiones.length; i++) {               
//              capturaSerie =capturaNumeroRegion(cadenaRegiones);
//          }
            
            //cadenaSerieCompleta=capturaSerie.split(separador).toString();
            
            

        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new CPagoException(e);
        }
        //return region;
        return ;
```

La variable `listRegion` es donde se guarda el resultado de una consulta que estoy ejecutando, esa consulta me trae:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues tengo la variable `capturaRegiones` que es la que guarda solo un registro que sería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues esta la variable `cadenaRegiones` que se encarga de guardar lo de la foto anterior que posteriormente con el metodo Split la divido con limitador ","

Posteriomente ya que están divididos los guarda en una arreglo que se llama `arrayRegiones`

Ese arreglo lo recorro dependiendo el tamaño que tiene el arreglo y dentro de ese for ejecuto otra función que se llama `capturaNumeroRegion` que recibe como parametro un solo numero, dicha función es la siguiente:

```
public String capturaNumeroRegion(String region) throws CPagoException{

        if(region.equals("1")) {
            region ="PA";           
        }       
        if(region.equals("2")) {
            region ="PB";           
        }       
        if(region.equals("3")) {
            region ="PC";           
        }       
        if(region.equals("4")) {
            region ="PD";           
        }       
        if(region.equals("5")) {
            region ="PE";           
        }       
        if(region.equals("6")) {
            region ="PF";           
        }       
        if(region.equals("7")) {
            region ="PG";           
        }       
        if(region.equals("8")) {
            region ="PH";           
        }       
        if(region.equals("9")) {
            region ="PI";           
        }
        
        return region;
        
    }
```

La función de arriba recibe un numero de tipo cadena, por ejm si agrego un "1" me regresará PA y asi sucesivamente.

La pregunta es, como puedo formar una cadena en base al numero de valla recibiendo la función `capturaNumeroRegion` y como resultado del metodo `cadenasRegionesAprocesarUpdate` me regrese el siguiente resultado:

"PA, PB" o cuantos mas `capturaNumeroRegion` valla recibiendo?

Espero y me puedan ayudar por favor, quedo al pendiente de sus comentarios en caso de que algo no se entienda, saludos y excelente tarde.

Comment: Te recomiendo cambiar tu método capturaNumeroRegion por un `switch case` en lugar de utilizar tantos `if`.

Comment: Hola buenas tardes, tambien eso es buena practica, pero como eran poquitos if, 9 en total por eso opté en hacerlo asi XD

Comment: Cuando mandas a llamar `capturaSerie = capturaNumeroRegion(cadenaRegiones);`, ya probaste así:  `capturaSerie += capturaNumeroRegion(cadenaRegiones);` pudiendo agregar un separador al final de la asignación.

Comment: Sería algo así?
 ´for (String numeroRegion : arrayRegiones) {    
    capturaSerie += separador +capturaNumeroRegion(cadenaRegiones);
   }´

Comment: Sí, eso o añadir el separador después de tu función capturaNumeroRegion, porque así como lo tienes actualmente no estas concatenando nada en tu cadena `capturaSerie` entonces siempre te dará el ultimo valor que retorne `capturaNumeroRegion` más no todos los resultados. Inténtalo.

Comment: Basicamente sería así?
´capturaSerie   +=capturaNumeroRegion(cadenaRegiones)+ separador;´?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112586/discussion-between-cratus666jose-and-redsalas).

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando Java 8, puedes utilizar [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) y sus metodos que son muy utiles para lo que quieres hacer, los pasos a aplicar son los siguientes:

1. Una vez que obtienes tu listado de **ParametrosVO** de la BD, aplicas un map sobre el listado obtenido para luego aplicar por cada iteración un split sobre el String de esa iteración, asi podrás generar un array de array de String, quedando algo asi:

   **Entrada:** ["1,2", "5,6,7"] -> **Salida:** [["1", "2"],["5","6","7"]]
2. Luego de obtener el array de array de String, usas flapmap para combinar esto en un solo array, quedando algo asi:

   **Entrada:** [["1", "2"],["5","6","7"]] -> **Salida:** ["1","2","5","6","7"]
3. Posterior a lo anterior aplicas el .collect(Collectors.toList()) para convertir el stream en un List de String
4. Para este paso puedes usar una enumeración o dejarlo tal cual con los if, pero si dejas los if te recomiendo anidarlos, ej:

**Metodo captura**

```
public String capturaNumeroRegion(String region) {
    if (region.equals("1")) {
        region = "PA";
    } else if (region.equals("2")) {
        region = "PB";
    } else if (region.equals("3")) {
        region = "PC";
    } else if (region.equals("4")) {
        region = "PD";
    } else if (region.equals("5")) {
        region = "PE";
    } else if (region.equals("6")) {
        region = "PF";
    } else if (region.equals("7")) {
        region = "PG";
    } else if (region.equals("8")) {
        region = "PH";
    } else if (region.equals("9")) {
        region = "PI";
    }
    return region;
}
```

5. Para los ultimos pasos, una vez que obtienes el listado de String aplicaras un map sobre la lista para que en cada iteración llames al metodo **capturaNumeroRegion** para asi obtener el nombre, lo que generará un nuevo listado de String, quedando asi:

   **Entrada:** ["1","2","5","6","7"] -> **Salida:** ["PA,PB,PE,PF,PG"]
6. Como ultimo paso, una vez obtenido el nuevo listado con las regiones aplicas .collect(Collectors.joining(",")) en donde le indicas el caracteres de union en este caso se utilizo el caracter "," quedando un solo String **"PA,PB,PE,PF,PG"**, tambien si no indicas alguno por defecto junta todas las letras (ej: "PAPBPEPFPG")

**Clase Test**

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

class CadenaRegionesTest {

    @Test
    void cadenaRegionesTest() {
        assertThat(cadenaRegionesAProcesarUpdate()).isEqualTo("PA,PB,PE,PF,PG");
    }

    @Getter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    class ParametrosVO {
        String clave;
        String valor;
    }

// Simula tú consulta a la BD
    public List<ParametrosVO> getParametrosVO() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                new ParametrosVO("REGIONPROCESAR", "1,2"),
                new ParametrosVO("REGIONPROCESAR", "5,6,7")
        );
    }

    public String cadenaRegionesAProcesarUpdate() {
        List<ParametrosVO> listRegiones = getParametrosVO();
//Aplicas los pasos 1, 2, 3
        List<String> regiones = listRegiones.stream().map(parametro -> parametro.getValor().split(","))
                .flatMap(Arrays::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
//Aplicas los pasos 5 y 6
        return regiones.stream().map(region -> capturaNumeroRegion(region)).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    }

//Aplicas paso 4
    enum RegionEnum {
        PA(1), PB(2), PC(3),
        PD(4), PE(5), PF(6),
        PG(7), PH(8), PI(9);

        public final Integer numero;

        RegionEnum(Integer numero) {
            this.numero = numero;
        }

    }
//Aplicas paso 4
    public String capturaNumeroRegion(String region) {
        Optional<RegionEnum> optionalRegionEnum = Arrays.stream(RegionEnum.values())
                .filter(regionEnum -> regionEnum.numero.equals(Integer.valueOf(region))).findFirst();
        return optionalRegionEnum.map(Enum::name).orElse(region);
    }
}
```